# Override system installation of gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, versioning, redmine

I'm installing Redmine and it requires a version of the i18n gem that is older than the one shipped with Fedora 15 (0.5.0).

I don't want to mess around with the system too much (IE sudo gem install -v=0.4.2 i18n) and interfere with the yum managed parts of the system; I was wondering how to install the required downgrade gem locally to the user running redmine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not doing it anyway, install [RVM, the Ruby Version Manager](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/).

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

Then do:

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
source .bash_profile
```

Just read the RVM documentation on how to install Rubies and Gems.

It keeps all your Ruby versions and Gems in your user home and does not interfere with the whole system. You can even keep different Gem sets for different versions and switch between them.